# Update HTML attributes depending on the total <li> jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I have a slider with items in a list that will vary depending on the page.

So, what I am looking to do is run a loop that will update the `data-slide-to` attribute with correct number for each slide.

After tons of trial and error I wrote something that *almost* works...

I use `$.each()` to get the index array for all the `<li>`'s and I use the `nth:child` selector and use the index to choose the `<li>` then use `.attr()` to change the HTML attribute with the index number.

**Full code:**

```js
var sliderList = $("ul#list li");

function updateDataNum(){
  $.each(sliderList, function( index, value ) {
    $( "ul#list li:nth-child" + '(' + index + ')').attr("data-slide-to",index);
  });
}

updateDataNum();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">One</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Two</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Three</li> 
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Four</li>
</ul>
```

**How the code starts**

```
<ul id="list">
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">One</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Two</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Three</li> 
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Four</li>
</ul>
```

**What I want to happen**

```
<ul id="list">
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="0">One</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="1">Two</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="2">Three</li> 
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="3">Four</li>
</ul>
```

**What *actually* happens**

```
<ul id="list">
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="1">One</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="2">Two</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="3">Three</li> 
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have complicated your code too much. A very simple solution is given in my answer. you can check that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nth-child` is 1-based, while `index` is 0-based.

Change to:

```
$( "ul#list li:nth-child" + '(' + (index + 1) ...
```

```js
var sliderList = $("ul#list li");

function updateDataNum(){
  $.each(sliderList, function( index, value ) {
    $( "ul#list li:nth-child" + '(' + (index + 1) + ')').attr("data-slide-to",index);
  });
}

updateDataNum();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">One</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Two</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Three</li> 
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can do all the assignments at once like this:

```
$("#list li").attr("data-slide-to", function(index) {
  return index;
});
```

```js
var sliderList = $("#list li");

function updateDataNum() {
  $("#list li").attr("data-slide-to", function(index) {
    return index;
  });
}

updateDataNum();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">One</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Two</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Three</li> 
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Four</li>
</ul>
```

In ES6, this can be simplified to:

```
$("#list li").attr("data-slide-to", index => index);
```

```js
var sliderList = $("#list li");

function updateDataNum() {
  $("#list li").attr("data-slide-to", index => index);
}

updateDataNum();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">One</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Two</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Three</li> 
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can simplify this even further by just not doing the nth-child lookup at all.  Why not just use `value.attr('data-slide-to', index)`?

Comment: Or use `$('#list li').each(function(idx)) { $(this).data('slide-to', idx); }`

Comment: @SteveT I'd add that as an answer as it's a much better solution

Answer (score 2):

Please simplified your code with the use of `$(this)` like below:-

```
$( this).attr("data-slide-to",(index+1)); // since index started from 0 so +1 needed
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each($("ul#list li"), function(index) {
    $( this).attr("data-slide-to",(index+1));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">One</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Two</li>  
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Three</li> 
  <li data-target="#video-slider" data-slide-to="">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of accessing the properties with attr('data-slide-to'), use the jquery built-in data function:

```
$('#list li').each(function(idx) { 
  $(this).data('slide-to', idx); 
});
```

The each function already comes with a zero-based index as a parameter.